# SQL Server : multiple small tables vs one large table for searching

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 25 tables with the same structure, but different data. Each table has 7 millions rows. To find a record I have to go through each table one by one i.e. search table 1, if the record is found then show it and exit otherwise search table 2 and so on until table 25.

The structure is:

```
Name, Cell Number, ID Card Number, Address
```

In performance perspective:

1. Is it ok or should I merge all tables to on large table.
2. At what extent I can combine the tables. (How many rows are good to be in one table and then another table should be created).

**Note**: I have only search query on Cell Number and ID card number

Comment: If you have many tables, with the same definition, this is almost always an indication of a design flaw, as you are using the table to infer information that should be in a column. This is only more apparent when you then want to treat the data as one object, like here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is better to store all rows in a single table rather than in multiple tables.  To speed queries, you should use facilities such as indexes and partitions.

Normally, when this question comes up, the issue is small tables (think dozens of rows) versus "large" tables (think thousands or millions of rows).  In that extreme case, the decision is more cut-and-dry:

- There is overhead to executing searches on multiple tables.  Preparing and running queries takes some effort.
- There is overhead in data storage.  Tables store rows on data pages and the pages are not shared with other tables.  If these pages are half-filled, then the I/O time is wasted.
- Any improvements on performance, such as indexes, are either wasted on small tables or need to be repeated ad infinitum.

In your case, with a handful of large tables, these considerations are weaker.  There is overhead for searching tables.  But then again, it takes some time to run a query against 7 million rows -- and if the query requires scanning the table, the compile time is much less than the execution time.  Such large tables have minuscule amount of wasted overhead in terms of half-filled "last" pages.

What I would say instead is that storing entities across multiple tables just makes managing the database trickier, so why bother?  If i had to guess, you have 25 months of history (24 months of history plus the current month).  I would recommend that you store such data in a single table, perhaps partitioned by month.

Comment: What if I have 100 tables?

Comment: @Khalil . . . My recommendation is to put everything in one table.  However, with a handful of tables the overhead to dealing with multiple tables may be manageable.  As the number of tables grows, it just becomes more and more bothersome -- and that is a separate concern from performance.

Comment: . . Management is not the problem. I have concern with performance. So if I have 100 tables each having 7-8 millions rows. Should I merge them to one?. If there is no difference between one and multiple tables with respect of performance then I will consider management. And thanks for your time.

Comment: @Khalil . . . One table will usually have better performance, because running one query has 100 times *less* query preparation overhead than running 100 queries.

Comment: @Khalil With proper indexing, a search on a table with *billions* of rows is almost instantaneous. For example, 1 billion rows in a B-Tree index has on average only log2(1billion) lookups to do, or about 30, which is not very much at all